# Outputting dates in to a table padding missing dates in order

Tags: php, arrays, date, logic, html-table

My array from a database looks like this:

```
$client[0]['Name'] = 'Foo';
$client[0]['Claim'][0]['year'] = 2013;
$client[0]['Claim'][1]['year'] = 2014;
$client[0]['Claim'][2]['year'] = 2015;

$client[1]['Name'] = 'Bar';
// no 2013!
$client[1]['Claim'][0]['year'] = 2014;
$client[1]['Claim'][1]['year'] = 2015;

// table headers are name, 2013, 2014, 2015...
foreach($client as $c) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $c['Client']['name'] . '</td>';
    foreach($c['Claim'] as $claim) :
     echo '<td>' . $claim['year'] . '</td>';
    endforeach;
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Which works fine except when a `$client` is missing a year then the `<td>` are not balanced; causing my table to be incorrect.

My goal is to have each `$claim['Year']` line up with the appropriate table heading.

I figured I could just add empty keys to each array and re-order them but that seems a bit unnecessary and wondered if there was a better way of doing it.

So an array might look

this would be ideal:

```
$years[null, 2014, 2015]
```

whereas currently it is

```
 $years[2014,2015]
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Seems you find the solution yourself, adding dummy values when the dates are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a start and an end year that you want to display the claims for. Then if you replace the inner for loop with this I think it should work:

```
$x = 0; //Variable to keep track of what claim we are on.
//Loop through the years.
for($i=$start; $i<=$stop; $i++) {
    //If there is a claim for this year, echo it and move on to the next claim.
    if($c['Claim'][$x]['year'] == $i) {
       echo '<td>' . $c['Claim'][$x]['year'] . '</td>';
       $x++;
    }
    //If not, just echo an empty table cell.
    else {
       echo '<td></td>';
    }
}
```

This only works if the claims are sorted by year. Please note that I have not tested the code.